# Listview Double Click

Tags: c#

My listview will display 3 columns from my database.

```
       ID          Username        Email
      ------------------------------------
       234            Joe          Micro@Gmail.com
       235            Jeff         Mozil@Yahoo.com 
       246            Jerry        Apple@Mircosoft.com
```

When I double click on the row I want to also get the 'Username' and 'Email' values from the selected row.

I have full row select set to true but it will only display the ID value.

```
    private void listView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewHitTestInfo hit = listView1.HitTest(e.Location);
        if (hit.Item != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(hit.Item.Text);
        };
```

Comment: hit.Item.Text + " " hit.Item.SubItems[1].Text + " " ..

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that TaW's answer is correct.

Correct code...

```
        ListViewHitTestInfo hit = listView1.HitTest(e.Location);
        if (hit.Item != null)
        {
        MessageBox.Show(hit.Item.Text + " " + hit.Item.SubItems[1].Text + " " + hit.Item.SubItems[2].Text + " ");       
        };
```